# VSCode tunnel: how to forward SFTP port?

Tags: visual-studio-code, port, sftp, vscode-remote

I use the VSCode "Remote Tunnel Access" (not the SSH Remote thing) service to connect from `ComputerA` to `ComputerB` and I want to be able to access the port `ComputerB:22` (SFTP) which in turn gives access to SFTP on `ComputerC`, all from `ComputerA:8123` (or any other available port on my local machine. See:

`|ComputerA:8123| ---(VSCodeTunnel)---> |ComputerB:22| ---(SFTP)---> |Computer:22|`

At the moment I managed to connect VSCode to ComputerB, then I tried forwarding port 22 using the "Ports View", it give me a link which looks like `https://abcdefgh-22.uks1.devtunnels.ms`. But I can't manage to use this link to access the remote port.

I tried a SFTP client to access `ComputerC` through port `8123` but it did not work.

How does the port forwarding works with the Remote Tunnel Access?

I have VSCode 1.81.1